# Programmatically create Amazon MTurk HITLayout and get HITLayoutId?

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, boto3, mechanicalturk

I'm wondering if there is an alternative to creating the [HITLayout](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSMechTurk/latest/AWSMturkAPI/ApiReference_HITLayoutArticle.html) from the website and doing it programmatically if I have the html file ready for it.

I know that I can create a project on the website and get the HITLayoutId that way but I am specifically asking for a way to do this programmatically in a similar fashion, creating a HIT Type by providing a html file and getting a LayoutId somehow so that I can go on to create HITs in bulk using Python's boto3 `create_hit_with_hit_type` function.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, no, the only way to get a HITLayoutId is by creating one from the website UI.